# Configuring and running Ruby-On-Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, aptana, dbmigrate

I'm (completely) new to ROR and have got an application to maintain and upgrade. I've the source code and am trying to build database using `db:migrate` rake command. I've started using Aptana Studio for the development. When I run `dg:migrate` I get following errors:

```
rake db:migrate
(in G:/Projects/.../.../trunk)
MissingSourceFile no such file to load -- rcov/rcovtask
WARNING: rcov tests won't work
Looking for release_type overrides ...
=> Loading G:/Projects/.../.../trunk/config/release_type_config.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.allow_concurrency=has been deprecated and
no longer has any effect. Please remove all references to allow_concurrency=.. 
(called from allow_concurrency= at D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/
activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/
connection_specification.rb:98)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.verification_timeout= has been deprecated
and no longer has any effect. Please remove all references to 
verification_timeout=.. (called from verification_timeout= at    
D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:108)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- hpricot
```

I've installed hpricot gem also (version 0.8).

What is the remedy for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significand error is

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- hpricot
```

You need hpricot. You can install it running the following command on the command line

```
gem install hpricot
```

Comment: @simone i'm getting this error on running `gem install hpricot` -> `Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hpricot:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for stdio.h... yes
creating Makefile
make
mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target `ruby.h', needed by `fast_xs.o'.  S
top.
Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.2
for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.2/ext/fast_xs/gem_m
ake.out`

Comment: This is because you don't have a compiler on your machine. You need to install a compiled Gem. Try specifying your environment `gem install hpricot --platform x86-mingw32`

Comment: no luck @simone getting same error. I've installed MinGW32 so I've gcc etc. If anything else is needed please let me know or if I can get compiled gems from somewhere.

Comment: `gem install hpricot --platform mswin32` worked fine. I got it from here: http://bit.ly/aBRXRU

Answer (score 3):

Install the rcov gem:

```
gem install relevance-rcov --source http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: The execution stopped at hpricot. The rcov requirement just generated a warning.

Comment: @neutrino I've checked and hpricot was not installed as gcc was not available. I've installed MinGW32 and mingw32-make. I tried to installed rcov using the command you provided and got this error: `mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target `ruby.h', needed by `callsite.o'.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your system can't find the gems. This could be a path problem, see [this post for details](http://blog.pretheory.com/arch/2008/02/capistrano_path_and_environmen.php).

Comment: @JRL I've properly configured the paths in Aptana settings and all the directories are registered in %path% env. variable